# Difference between Proactive Caching on Partitions, Dimensions, and Measure Groups

Tags: reporting-services, ssas

After reading much of the documentation, I'm still unclear about proactive caching being set in various places: in the Partitions, on the Dimensions, and on the Measure Groups.

What is the difference between setting them in these various place, and where would one need to set proactive caching for SSRS reports to be current (in my case I'd be using scheduled polling)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you configure proactive caching for a dimension, then that will keep the dimension current with the source.  A customer dimension is one where you might consider enabling proactive caching...where as a date dimension is (typically) static so you wouldn't need to configure proactive caching for that one (unless you had a current date flag or something like that).

MeasureGroup and Partition proactive caching is specific to your fact data.  The difference is simply the granularity.  If you want all partitions in the measure group to use the same proactive caching settings, you would configure it at the measure group level.  However, if only the data in the most recent partition is changing (say current month), then you could just configure proactive caching on that particular partition.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.  For some reason it's just not working for me as intended.  I have MOLAP setup to poll every 10 minutes, on the dimensions, but I never see any changes.  I still need to reprocess the dimensions to get the data to change.  I'll research this more and perhaps create another post if I can't get it figured out.